# Is there a family of functions that includes triangle, sin, and square waves?

Tags: periodic-functions, parametrization

Is there a family of functions that includes triangle, sin, and square waves?

[image: sin, square, saw, and triangle]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tfy0.png)

If so, is there a way to parametrise them such that a single parameter sweeps from triangle through sin to square? Something like how kurtosis sweeps through the t-distributions?

[image: t distributions with differing kurtosis]

Finally, if the answer is 'yes' to both of the above, then is there something equivalent to skewness that would result in a saw wave, when the first parameter was set to a triangle wave?

Comment: square : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2 \pi (2n-1) x)}{2 n -1}$, saw-tooth : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2 \pi n x)}{n}$, triangle : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2 \pi n x)}{n^2}$, sine : $\sin(2 \pi x)$

Comment: hence I'd say what you are searching for is $f_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2 \pi n x)}{n^\alpha}$ (the square being $f_1(x) - \frac{f_1(2x)}{2}$, the sine : $f_\infty(x)$, the triangle : $f_2(x)$, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Using linear combination of $\sin$ functions and $\cos$ you can express any periodic function
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx$$
It's called Fourier series
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html

I'm not sure about single parameter sweep. You surely can transform between them freely with linear transformations (all these functions simply have different coordinates in the basis of $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions)

Comment: Yeah, I know about Fourier series, but this doesn't really answer the question. Although I guess there might be a parameterisable function/surface of the Fourier series coefficients that would do it.

Comment: I think that one way to do it is following - the less coefficients you use for triangular wave the more 'sin-like' the wave is. so you go from triangular to sin by taking off coefficients and then to square by adding coefficients

Comment: Yeah, ideally the parameter sweep would evolve smoothly from one function to the next (e.g. continuous in the parameter dimension as well as the x dimension).

Comment: well you can add/remove the additional coefficients smoothly, for example for smooth transition between 10th and 11th coefficient of the square wave you could use
$$\sum_{n=0}^{10}\frac{\sin(2n+1)x}{2n+1}+\alpha\frac{\sin(22+1)x}{22+1},\ \alpha\in[0,1]$$
do you need it for any specific application?

Comment: No I actually think that's no good. It doesn't convert to the square wave as you would probably wish (as painted in your  picture)

Comment: well what about this: you know the formula for $\sin$, for square wave and for triangular wave. so you can consider this to be basis. for sweeping between triangular and $\sin$ you use $t\cdot\mathrm{triagnle}(x)+(1-t)\sin(x)$

Comment: Need: not really. I was just thinking about being able to smoothly morph between synth sounds (and being able to produce nice sounds in between the common patterns), and wondered if this might be a way to do it. The last suggestion sounds sensible, although I'd guess the sin wave doesn't lie directly in between the triangle and square, but I guess you could just split it into two sweeps.. That might make the second parameter impossible to figure out though. Interesting.

Comment: what second parameter?

Comment: "skewness" kind of thing - last sentence in the question.